# Create an object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mapping

I'm trying to convert the array to map, 
The array looks like :

```
var array = [{
  "id" : 123
}, {
  "id" : 456
}, {
  "id" : 789
}];
```

The final object I'm trying to build should look like :

```
var result = {
  "123": { id: 123 } , 
  "456": { id: 456 } , 
  "789": { id: 789 }
};
```

Any efficient way to implement it will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Your expected output is very ambiguous.  Use actual values in the input and output, rather than psuedo code that is unclear.

Comment: Question explanation is obvious.

Comment: @Usman explain it then.  It's definitely not obvious at all.

Comment: I don't think stack-overflow is like code repository, it is not necessarily the code taken by there should be run on compiler without syntax error.

Comment: @Usman I absolutely agree, but if the OP posts something ambiguous and says *"I want to get this"* and that is also ambiguous then posting anything other than a question to gain clarity is just clutter and a waste of time for future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var array = [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "otherProp": "true"
    },
    {
        "id": 456,
        "otherProp": "false"
    },
    {
        "id": 789,
        "otherProp": "true"
    }
];
var result = array.reduce(function (acc, cur, i) {
    acc[cur.id] = cur;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Use javaScript `reduce`

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

Comment: If you put some values in this and convert it to a snippet so it runs then it may prove to be exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, your answer is same as mine!

Comment: I added code snippets for future visitors to readability of question. If some one will insist then i will remove my answer.

Comment: I don't think all developers can understand arrow functions

Comment: You don't have to remove your answer. And yes, all devs may not understand arrow functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce`

```js
var array = [{
  "id" : 123
}, {
  "id" : 456
}, {
  "id" : 789
}];

var expectedValue = {
  "123": { id: 123 } , 
  "456": { id: 456 } , 
  "789": { id: 789 }
};

var result = array.reduce( (acc, c) => (acc[ c.id ] = c, acc) ,{});

console.log('result : ', result);
console.log('(JSON.stringify(expectedValue) === JSON.stringify(result)) ? ', (JSON.stringify(expectedValue) === JSON.stringify(result)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Explanation**

- Use `reduce` to iterate and **initialize the accumulator** to `{}`
- Set the key as `id` of item of every iteration `c` and value as `c` itself.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal ... at least, regarding `{array[0]}`, `{array[1]}` and so on, it is almost obvious what the OP wants, since the provided code reads `var array = [ {"id" : 123, ... }, ...`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal ... the answer you criticize for not being correct also provides code that exactly produces the result the OP was asking for. Thus you never tried the code yourself but immediately jumped to a conclusion that does not justify itself. What still might be criticized is the one liner without any explanation. If it, in addition, was provided as working example code the misunderstanding you were running in might have been prevented. You might think about dropping the downvote in case you did it out of anger.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thanks for the edit. I was about to add a demo as well.